# jQuery Ajaxy : get only an element from an html file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery Ajaxy plugin: http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-ajaxy.

My website has two languages (english/greek).

When the ajax request is executed , it is calling the html file which includes the two languages texts, sepetarating its other with two divs `ex: <div id="en"></div>`.

So with simple ajax load function I was doing it like this:

`$("#text").load("contactus.html #en")`

Is this also possible with the **ajaxy** plugin?

Comment: Use this
**$("#text").load("contactus.html #en");**

Answer (score 0):

See this URL: http://balupton.github.com/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

Look at the section **"The JavaScript"**

In Ajaxy, both for the generic controller and the page controller, there are a common sequence of actions:

```
var data = this.State.Response.data;
```

This data is the full html blob of the page you requested. You can do some tampering here, inside both the response handlers for the generic controller and the page controller.

For example, after the above line:

```
var xdoc = $($.parseXML(data + '')); //performance hit if your page is really complex
var enDivHTMLStr = xdoc.find('div#en').text();
var esDivHTMLStr = xdoc.find('div#es').text();
data = enDivHTMLStr; //or esDivHTMLStr
```